# [Android][kotlin] How to set 'scheme' for intent

Tags: android, kotlin

i am a beginner in Android.

I wrote the following codes:

```
        val button_2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button_2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

```
        <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity">
            <intent-filter xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I just wonder if i can substitute the xml configuration `<data android:scheme="https">` for something like

```
        val button_2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button_2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")
            intent.scheme = "https"
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

But the `Android Documentation` show me that there is no `setScheme` in Intent Class.

`If there is other magic methods that i can use?`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your custom scheme in manifest file like below :

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" >

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="myhostname"/>

            <data android:scheme="myCustomScheme"
                android:host="myAnotherHostName"/>


        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is open a link when you press the button. is it correct?

Comment: yes. i don't want to ues xml configuration way to open a link.